# Spring boot not generating java classes from soap wsdl in maven project.Here is my pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client

Question-I'm trying to create a soap client to consume SOAP Webservice.But Java classes are not getting created for below wsdl.Spring boot+maven project.My wsdl is up and running in browser also.
Here is the wsdl name
http://p61vmcfgsvstg06.production.online.dell.com/ConfigService/V3/ConfigService.svc?wsdl

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.javaspringclub</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBoot_SOAP_Client_Movies</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SpringBoot_SOAP_Client_Movies</name>
<description>WebService Example</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>catalog.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://p61vmcfgsvstg06.production.online.dell.com/ConfigService/V3/ConfigService.svc?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Spring Boot is a code library used at runtime. Generating classes from WSDL is done at compile time by *your* build script. Don't blame Spring Boot for flaws in *your* build script.